# Parse Relational Queries

Tags: android, parse-platform, relational

I am struggling with Parse Relational Queries.

What I want to do: To query all Recipes that current ParseUser likes.

**Models (Pseudo code to simplify)**
There are two classes. One is Recipe class, another one is Like class that has information of who likes which recipe.

```
@ParseClassName("Like")
public class Like ParseObject{
    "fromUser" : ParserUser 
    "toRecipe": Recipe
}

@ParseClassName("Recipe")
public class Recipe : ParseObject {
    "objectId": String // from ParseObject
    // some other field.
}
```

I have tried both whereMatchesQuery() and whereMatchesKeyInQuery() methods. But both query results are an empty list. Does someone know how to query to meet my requirement?

**Case of using ParseQuery.whereMatchesQuery()**

```
ParseQuery<Like> likesQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Like.class);
likesQuery.whereEqualTo("fromUser", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
ParseQuery<Recipe> recipesQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Recipe.class);
recipesQuery.whereMatchesQuery("toRecipe",  likesQuery);
recipesQuery.find() <- Return Empty List
```

**Case of using ParseQuery.whereMatchesKeyInQuery()**

```
ParseQuery<Like> likesQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Like.class);
likesQuery.whereEqualTo("fromUser", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
ParseQuery<Recipe> recipesQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Recipe.class);
recipesQuery.ParseQuerywhereMatchesKeyInQuery("objectId", toRecipe", likesQuery);
recipesQuery.find() <- Return Empty List
```

Comment: I would think the last example would work (apart for some syntax). There are no ACL restrictions or something like that preventing you from getting results?

Comment: @cYrixmorten, Thank you for the reply. I also believe 2nd would work. But no query results. It seems something is wrong. I did not set any ACL.

Answer (score 1):

With the current design, it seems you can only fetch likes and then get `Recipe`s with get:

```
ParseQuery<Like> likesQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Like.class);
likesQuery.whereEqualTo("fromUser", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
List<Like> likes = likesQuery.find();
List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList(likes.size());
for (Like like : likes) {
    recipes.add(like.getRecipe());
}
```

You can use `query.include()` to include the recipe object in the query results.

Another option is to add a recipe id field to likes:

```
@ParseClassName("Like")
public class Like ParseObject {
    "fromUser" : ParserUser 
    “toRecipe” : Recipe
    "toRecipeId": String
}
```

If you do this, you can use your second suggestion with `whereMatchesKeyInQuery`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try your second suggestion. Also, thank you for first suggestion, it is not suitable with what I'd like to do. I'd like to use Query.or(...) to combine with other queries. Thanks!